# A list of all the Windows 8.1 updates

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, windows-update

I am trying to find a list of some sort, which lists all the released updates (I mean every single one of them), for a specific version of Windows in release-date order. Does anyone happen to know if such a list exists or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get update lists from [Windows updates downloader site](http://www.windowsupdatesdownloader.com/UpdateLists.aspx):

> The Update Lists (ULs) contain the necessary list of updates for each
>   of the versions of Windows listed below. You will also find ULs for
>   other software such as Office and Exchange.

- Download `ulz` file for your OS
- Rename to zip
- Unpack
- Rename unpacked file to `xml`
- Open with any text\xml viewer

> by the way are you a hundred percent positive that this list has all
>   the updates ever released for windows 8.1 listed?

I'm not sure that those lists include superseded\declined updates and all revisions\rereleases (more about terminology [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc708465.aspx)). It makes no sense from the practical standpoint. If you really need a list of every update ever released, the only thing that I can think of is to deploy a WSUS server, approve all updates for particular system and grab them using [this](https://angrytechnician.wordpress.com/2011/04/28/how-to-get-a-list-of-every-wsus-update-using-powershell/) or similar script.

Comment: awesome, thanks, very super close to what I needed.

Comment: by the way are you a hundred percent positive that this list has all the updates ever released for windows 8.1 listed?

Comment: @AbrahamLincool Unfortunately, no. See update for suggestions.